# Magento 2, xdebug when cron running show issue with bin/magento

Tags: magento2, cron, debug, xdebug

When I run cron with debugging. I get the message like this
[image]

It takes so long time to run my cron.
So anyone knows to fix this issue? Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Add **n98-magerun2.phar** on Magento Root Directory.

```
curl -sS -O https://files.magerun.net/n98-magerun2.phar

chmod +x ./n98-magerun2.phar
```

**Try this on Magento Root**

```
sudo ./n98-magerun2.phar sys:cron:run digitec_galaxus_order
```